# How to add a line with a unique string to a file and a directory with that same string in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv file of a few hundred lines. Each of these lines starts with some identifier of seven numbers. In bash, I need to create a directory for each unique identifier, and inside each directory, create a csv file containing the lines starting with that unique identifier. For example, for this line in my original csv:

`7988114_lig2,c1cccc(Cl)c1CSc(n2)nn(c23)C(C4=C(N3)CCCC4=O)c5cccnc5,-6.18411530082281`

I need to create a directory named `7988114`, and a csv named `7988114.csv` and then copy each line in my original csv that starts with `7988114` into the `7988114.csv`.

I have already written code to create directories with the correct names. Speed is not a big issue so I have tried many seemingly straightforward and roundabout ways to create csv files in the appropriate directories and place the correct lines in those csv files, but I am not well-versed in bash. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Only a few hundred lines? Around how many different identifiers?

Comment: There are around 50 unique identifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you want to create a directory for each unique 7-digit id (first 7-characters in each line) and want to include all lines beginning with that id in a file within that directory named "`id`.csv", you can do what you need with `awk` alone. So long as the ID you are interested in is always the first 7 characters of the line, you can do:

```
awk -F, '{
    id=substr($1, 1, 7)
    system("[ -d " id " ] ||  mkdir " id)
    print $0 > id "/" id ".csv"
}' file.csv
```

With your example input it would create the directory `7988114` with file `7988114.csv` containing the entire line, e.g.

```
$ cat 7988114/7988114.csv
7988114_lig2,c1cccc(Cl)c1CSc(n2)nn(c23)C(C4=C(N3)CCCC4=O)c5cccnc5,-6.18411530082281
```

All lines with the same `id` would be appended to the same file resulting in the creation of a directory for each unique `id` and a text file named "`id`.csv" containing all lines for that unique `id`.

Answer (score 1):

4 line bash script with a for-each loop.  For every line in the original file, cut the identifier off of the beginning, then find all line matches in the original file and save them.

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `cat original.csv`; do
    filename="${line%%_*}"
    cat original.csv | grep $filename > $filename/$filename.csv
done
```

Slightly inefficient in the fact that repeat lines will do the same work, but bash scripting tends to be less about speed of execution and more about speed and simplicity of creation.

Comment: For future readers, this answer works perfectly for my needs as well, but is about a third slower than the accepted answer when I added it to my script.

Comment: Read abiout UUOC award (useless use of cat). you can just write `grep "$filename" original.csv`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's not so many unique identifiers that leaving one file open per identifier will make you hit the limit on how many open files a process can have, this perl script should do the trick:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

my %files;

while (<>) {
  if (/^(\d{7})/) {
    my $id = $1;
    unless (exists $files{$id}) {
      mkdir $id;
      open $files{$id}, ">", "$id/$id.csv";
    }
    my $fh = $files{$id};
    print $fh $_;
  } else {
    warn "Invalid line $_";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=test.csv

while -r read line ;do
 id="${line%%_*}"
 [[ -d "$id" ]] && continue #already processed
 mkdir "$id"
 grep -E "^$id" "$file" > "$id/$id.csv"
done < "$file"
```

but if you care about speed awk should be faster than bash.